# Div erased by writing to parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a javascript calculator for a project.
I wanted a red "E" to appear top left of the "#Total" div.
I put a small div("#hint") inside the total div, styled the Total
div with position: relative, and "hint" div position:absolute.
But, as soon as I write any thing ( e.g. a digit) to the 
Total div ( with JQuery ), the hint div disappears. And since the program starts by
writing a "0" to the Total div, you can never see the "E"..
I've tried setting the z-index of the hint div( to 99 ), but doesn't seem to work.

here is the index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

          <div id="calculator">

            <div id="total">
                <a id="hint">E</a>
            </div>

            <div id="operators">
                <a id="add">+</a>
                <a id="sub">-</a>
                <a id="divi">/</a>
                <a id="mult">*</a>
                <a id="equals">=</a>
            </div>
            <div id="numbers">
                <a id="n1">1</a>
                <a id="n2">2</a>
                <a id="n3">3</a>
                <a id="n4">4</a>
                <a id="n5">5</a>
                <a id="n6">6</a>
                <a id="n7">7</a>
                <a id="n8">8</a>
                <a id="n9">9</a>
                <a id="clear">CE</a>
                <a id="n0">0</a>
                <a id="clearall">AC</a>
                <a id="decimalPt">.</a>
                <a id="minus">+-</a>
            <!--    <a id="X">X</a>  -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is ( part of the ) css file: ( only need to consult through
"total"..)

```
body, div, a {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


#container {
    width:960px;
    margin: 10px auto;

}

#calculator {

    background-color: #999;
    width: 310px;
    height: 540px;
    border: 3px black solid;
    margin: 10px; 
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#hint {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#total {
    position: relative;     
    height: 70px;
    width: 300px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:white;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 60px;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

#numbers, #operators {
    margin: auto;   
}

#operators a {
    display: block;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 39px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 5px 6px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#numbers a {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32pt;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px 15px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#numbers > a#clearall {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#numbers > a#clearall:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
}

#numbers > a:hover:not(#clearall) {
    background-color: #00F;
    color: white;
}
```

The JQuery is in a separate file. The line that
causes the erasure is $("#total").text("0");

Hope you all can help...

Comment: Instead of using `position:relative`, use two divs with `display:inline-block` - then write the numbers to the second div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line of code:

```
$("#total").text("0");
```

will clear all child elements from `#total`.  That's what it is designed to do.  If you want to only affect part of the content of `#total` and leave the child elements there, then you need to target a specific child element in `#total` and change only that.

Perhaps what you want to do is this:

```
<div id="total">
    <span id="totalNum"></span>
    <a id="hint">E</a>
</div>
```

And, then you can target:

```
 $("#totalNum").text("0");
```

and adjust CSS formatting appropriately.  Then, your hint will not be disturbed when you change the totalNum.

Comment: jfriend00, thanks so much! This works perfectly. In all my study of JQuery, I do not remember that .text() erased all the child elements. Oh well, now I've learned something valuable..

Comment: @PhilD'Agostino - since it looks like you may be new here, if you get an answer to your question, then you can indicate that to the community by checking the green checkmark to the left of the best answer.  This will earn both you and the person who provided the answer some reputation points which can lead to more privileges on the site.

Comment: Thanks, jfriend! Well.. not exactly new, just have not asked many questions, and far between them..I have checked your answer...